# jQuery append not working in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-8, append

I'm having a problem with jQuery append just in Internet Explorer 8 (I didn't check earlier versions). On launch (in a `ready()` function) I append a `div` to my container `div`. This doesn't work in IE8 though, no div is added. I checked this by returning the length of $('div#options') in the console. Why isn't this working?

This is my code to append the div:

```
$('div#container').append('<div id="options"><a href="#" id="delete"><a href="#content" id="edit"></div>');
```

I also tried to use `prepend()` and `appendTo()`, but they didn't work either... Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps your broken links are causing the issue

```
$('div#container').append('<div id="options"><a href="#" id="delete">Delete</a><a href="#content" id="edit">Edit</a></div>');
```

Comment: This indeed was the problem. I decided to mark mcgrailm's answer though, since he was a bit earlier. Nonetheless thanks for the help!

Comment: Please recheck the times :) Either way, still glad I could help.

Comment: So almost 7 years later this should be changed, smh @Frog

Answer (score 4):

try it like this

```
 $('#container').append('<div id="options"><a href="#" id="delete">delete</a><a href="#content" id="edit">edit</a></div>');
```

[working demo tested in ie8](http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/J9wZu/)

Comment: Thanks! I must have looked at the code too much, can't believe I missed something that easy.

Answer (score 1):

In IE it is possible that DOM is not updated after the append. Use another method to ensure if the tag is appended or not. (For example use Developer Tools)

Comment: That's right... I always forget this. In IE 7 at least F12 (Developer Tools) there's a refresh button in the `HTML` that allows you to refresh the HTML after jQuery append do its thingy. :)